# Can't make POST request from Postman

Tags: rest, backendless

I have database in backendless, where I am trying to make POST request. If I open rest console in backendless admin page, there is no problem with making correct POST request. However when I want to make POST from postman it doesn't work, I get error

```
"code": 8002,
"message": "Could not parse request with message: Error decoding json body: null, status code 400, headers POST
```

Here is screenshot from [backendless](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynx8q.jpg) as well as from [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZrPg.jpg). I don't understand, why it is working only from backendless console. Could someone help me, where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: In postman, try adding Accept header as application/json. If it didnt work, can you try with curl requests ? Thats will give a perfect request structure. I too have seen sometimes postman add some unnecessary headers to the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make POST request with JSON body.
To do it, add
`Content-Type: application/json` header and define the json body in [raw Body tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfNQG.png)

Comment: Thank you, that was a problem. And one more question. If I would like to send POST by method which I have on postman screenshot, it is possible to do it with backendless?

Comment: @lkip0209 Do you mean with Backendless rest console? I think, yes. Anyway you can try it by yourself ;)

Comment: There is built-in Postman integration. See the screenshot at: https://take.ms/Gq2dx

Answer (score 0):

I found it confusing too, before I watched a video and realized that I needed to type into the text editor under the Body tab directly under the POST request URL, and not in the output section.

[screenshot from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ppLZ.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).